# Does WinRT support assembly binding redirection?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, assembly-resolution

.NET 1.0-4.0 supports it but Silverlight/WindowsPhone does not.

Does WinRT support assembly binding redirection?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Comment: Did you look at the [.Net 4.5 Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: .NET 4.5 and WinRT are different frameworks.

Comment: Are you asking about WinRT proper, or .NET Core, which integrates with WinRT?  WinRT itself doesn't really have a concept of assemblies at all. (An activatable type's full name uniquely identifies the type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't but strong named assemblies can automatically bind to assemblies where the version is greater than the one expected.